# Where can i find g4 file for G4 structure ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I would like to validate G4 structure file with ANTLR 4... is it possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i build a website to validate g4 file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713898/how-can-i-build-a-website-to-validate-g4-file)

Comment: What do you mean ? Check the correctness of the grammar itself ? (Ecris-moi, je traduirai)

Comment: Bonjour, Merci pour ton aide. En fait je recherche une méthode pour traduire un code pseudo "C" en java. Mais je but sur le traitement des codes "include" et des commentaires à la ligne type "n := 12 ! Commentaire ".... Tu connais quelqu'un qui pourrais m'aider à débugger ma grammaire g4 ? et m'aider à réaliser un code pseudo JAVA ? Merci

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for ANTLRv4Parser.g4 and ANTLRv4Lexer.g4.  You will find them in the source code download for the "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" book on the Pragmatic Bookshelf website (pragprog.com).  Check in the code/reference directory.